# Spring boot with querydsl create a query with function

Tags: java, spring-boot, geolocation, querydsl

i am using Spring Boot with querydsl. I need to build this query somehow, but i can't do it:

```
SELECT address.id, address.city FROM address WHERE earth_box( ll_to_earth(48.97300592, 8.32746506), 3100) @> ll_to_earth(address.lattitude, address.longitude);
```

I try to customize the binding method of that parameter in my `customize()` method

How can i build this query?

EDIT:

My customize() method in ArticleRepositoryImpl

```
@Override
    public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QArticle root) {

        bindings.bind(root.address.city).first((path, value) -> {

            Predicate city = root.address.city.eq(value); // Here i need to build my Predicate, which is my SqL query in the top

            return city;
        });
```

And my Rest Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/article")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<QArticle>> findAll(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Article.class) Predicate predicate,
            Pageable p) {

        System.out.println(predicate.toString());
        Page<QArticle> resultPage = repo.findAll(predicate, p);

        return new ResponseEntity<Page<QArticle>>(resultPage, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Show what you've done

Comment: I edit my comment and edit my customize method. More i don't have, because i am absolutely new to qerydsl and i dont know how to implement my predicate. Would be nice if you could help